# Converting PHPMailer HTML message to Text Message

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I wish to send an email using HTML if allowed by the client, else text.  Something like the following:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$htmlMessage="Hello John,<br /><br />How are you?";
$textMessage="Hello John,\n\nHow are you?";
$mail->Body =  $htmlMessage; 
$mail->AltBody  =  $textMessage;
```

I don't wish to write out the whole message for both, however, but create one version, and automatically convert it to the second.

Given this exact message, should I just create `$textMessage`, and then use `nl2br()` to add the HTML line breaks?

What if my HTML message was a bit more complicated and included bold text, a list, etc?  I am okay with the Text message being somewhat ugly, but don't want a bunch of HTML tags in the message.  What are my options for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, you do know that PHPMailer has *two* built-in HTML to plain text converters? `Strip_tags` is a pretty poor solution - it often results in an unreadable mess. The best results I've got come from using a real text-based browser (specifically [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz)) which can make a great job of rendering HTML as text, able to do things like preserve multi-column layouts, underlining, link references and some CSS. However, shelling out isn't always an option, so PHP solutions exist.

PHPMailer does an automatic conversion for the plain text version in `msgHTML()`, so your code would simply be this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$htmlMessage="Hello John,<br /><br />How are you?";
$mail->msgHTML($htmlMessage);
```

There is an option for a slightly more advanced converter (bundled in the `extras` folder) which you can trigger by setting the 'advanced' param in `msgHTML`:

```
$mail->msgHTML($htmlMessage, '', true);
```

Try them both, see what works best for you - but it's always worth reading the docs and source code!

**Update** Since I posted this answer, PHPMailer has had to remove the bundled html2text class for license reasons, but the mechanism for plugging in your own converter has been improved - the `advanced` parameter can now be a closure through which you can implement your own converter, such as any of those you might find [on packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=html2text).

Comment: Thanks Syncro.  At first I didn't realize that `msgHTML()` automatically creates an alt version, but later found it did (however, didn't know there were two of them!).  This is likely a better answer, and I will likely change my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Though not 100% good looking (depending on the HTML contents), [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will do what you want.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$htmlMessage="Hello John,<br /><br />How are you?";
$textMessage="Hello John,\n\nHow are you?";
$mail->Body =  $htmlMessage; 
$mail->AltBody  =  strip_tags( $htmlMessage );
```

You would not want to use `nl2br()` since AltBody is expecting plain text only. Any HTML formatting will appear (thus `<br/>` would show as text within your content). You could do something like:

```
$mail->AltBody  =  strip_tags( str_replace( $htmlMessage, array( '<br>', '<br/>', '<br />' ), "\r\n" ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Set Sail,  This seems to be a good compromise.  Sounds like best to generate the HTML version if I feel most users will be receiving that version. For text users, I suppose I should first do `str_replace('<br>','/n');` to make the text version at least decent.